# Julia implementation for converting string to snake_case/CamelCase

Tags: python, string, julia

I am looking for an implementation of the python library https://pypi.org/project/stringcase/
in Julia.

I found the following packages, but they seem all a bit outdated:

- https://github.com/KristofferC/Case.jl
- https://github.com/djsegal/StringCases.jl

Is there an up-to-date Julia library for converting strings to `snake_case`, `CamelCase` etc?

**Edit**: I have the following use-case:

I receive a JSON from a `C#` framework that uses *CamelCase* naming convention, which I load into a `DataFrame`.
The resulting DataFrame has column names like: `timeStamp`, `askBestVolume`, `askBest30MWPrice`. I'd like to convert the column names to the *snake_case*
naming convention, i.e.

```
"timeStamp" => "time_stamp"
"askBestVolume" => "ask_best_volume"
"askBest30MWPrice" => "ask_best_30MW_price"
...
```

The first two examples are rather simple and should be covered by a basic `snake_case(name_in_camel_case::String)` function. The third example would require defining "reserved words" that are ignored in the conversion.

Comment: What's wrong with StringCases.jl?

Comment: I realise, I phrased my question improper. I was discouraged by the lack of activities in the recent years and was wondering, if `StringCases.jl` is indeed the right package to use or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Maybe an example of what you need would help determine whether `StringCases.jl` is what you need or not. From your question, it does appear it is what you seek.

Comment: Sure, I added an example, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use "reserved words" as mentioned in the question, but instead assumes that a series of upper case letters (along with preceding numbers if any, for eg. "30MW") is supposed to be a word of its own; while also ensuring that "Price" in "30MWPrice" is seen as a separate word.

```
function snake_case(camelstring::S) where S<:AbstractString

  wordpat = r"
  ^[a-z]+ |                  #match initial lower case part
  [A-Z][a-z]+ |              #match Words Like This
  \d*([A-Z](?=[A-Z]|$))+ |   #match ABBREV 30MW 
  \d+                        #match 1234 (numbers without units)
  "x

  smartlower(word) = any(islowercase, word) ? lowercase(word) : word
  words = [smartlower(m.match) for m in eachmatch(wordpat, camelstring)]

  join(words, "_")
end

using Test

function runtests()
  @test snake_case("askBest30MWPrice") == "ask_best_30MW_price"
  @test snake_case("welcomeToAIOverlords") == "welcome_to_AI_overlords"
  @test snake_case("queryInterface") == "query_interface"
  @test snake_case("tst") == "tst"
  @test snake_case("1234") == "1234"
  @test snake_case("column12Value") == "column_12_value"
  @test snake_case("readTOC") == "read_TOC"
end
```

*(Probably Unimportant) Side Note*: You can replace `[a-z]` with `[[:lower:]]` and `[A-Z]` with `[[:upper:]]` above to make it work for some more languages, for eg. `snake_case("helloΩorld")` will then return `"hello_ωorld"`. However (like with anything Unicode), there are nuances - for eg., my language (Tamil) doesn't have letter cases, so its letters fall outside both `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]`.
A proper Unicode solution using `\p{Lo}`, `[:digit:]`, and whatever else, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Maybe unimportant but definitely interesting. Why is the part `(?=[A-Z]|$)` necessary?

Comment: The `[A-Z]` is necessary to make sure that we don't match the P in "30MWPrice" i.e. to avoid matching the capital letter that's actually part of the next word. The `|$` is in case the abbreviation comes at the end of the string, like in `readTOC` - there we want to match the last uppercase letter too, since there is no "next word" there.

Answer (score 1):

The snakecase function in the [python library](https://github.com/okunishinishi/python-stringcase/blob/master/stringcase.py) you referenced looks like this:

```
def snakecase(string):
    string = re.sub(r"[\-\.\s]", '_', str(string))
    if not string:
        return string
    return lowercase(string[0]) + re.sub(r"[A-Z]", lambda matched: '_' + lowercase(matched.group(0)), string[1:])

snakecase("timeStamp") #time_stamp
snakecase("askBestVolume") #ask_best_volume
snakecase("askBest30MWPrice") #ask_best30_m_w_price
```

One way to write it in julia is:

```
function snakecase(string)
    string = replace(string, r"[\-\.\s]" => "_")
    words = lowercase.(split(string, r"(?=[A-Z])"))
    return join([i==1 ? word : "_$word" for (i,word) in enumerate(words)])
end

snakecase("timeStamp") #time_stamp
snakecase("askBestVolume") #ask_best_volume
snakecase("askBest30MWPrice") #ask_best30_m_w_price
```

Note however that "askBest30MWPrice" is not handled the way you wrote (in either function)

Comment: Instead of manually prefixing each word with an underscore, you could use the separator argument to the `join` function, i.e. `return join(words, "_")`